# Websocket выдает ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, websocket

Пытаясь подключится к localhost:3000 выдает ошибку (в названии), я пробовал подключать вебсокет по адресу "localhost:3000", "localhost", "3000", все кроме localhost выдает тоже самое, localhost говорит ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```js
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:3000");
```

````js
// serverside
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");
const ws = require("ws");
const wss = new ws.Server({ noServer: true });
const sockets = new Set()

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == "GET") {
        res.end(fs.readFileSync("./index.html"));
        return
    }

    wss.handleUpgrade(req, req.socket, Buffer.alloc(0), onSocketConnection);
})
app.listen(3000);

function onSocketConnection(ws) {
    sockets.add(ws);
    console.log(ws);
}```
````

Comment: `wss` - использование подключения с `https`. Используйте просто `ws`.

Comment: Я уже понял но спасибо